# ExtJs GridPanel freeze/lock multiple columns

Tags: extjs, freeze, gridpanel, locked

Though ExtJs GridPanel is rich datacontrol , it has restricted columns freezing functionality.
Only first column can be freezed via locked attribute.
Has anyone solved this problem ?

Here is my code:

```
Ext.require(['Ext.grid.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.util.*', 'Ext.state.*']);
Ext.onReady(function () {
    // sample static data for the store
    var myData = [
        ['3m Co', 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Altria Group Inc', 83.81, 0.28, 0.34, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American Express Company', 52.55, 0.01, 0.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American International Group, Inc.', 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['AT&T Inc.', 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Boeing Co.', 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Caterpillar Inc.', 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Citigroup, Inc.', 49.37, 0.02, 0.04, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51, 1.28, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Exxon Mobil Corp', 68.1, -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Electric Company', 34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Motors Corporation', 30.27, 1.09, 3.74, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Hewlett-Packard Co.', 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Honeywell Intl Inc', 38.77, 0.05, 0.13, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Intel Corporation', 19.88, 0.31, 1.58, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['International Business Machines', 81.41, 0.44, 0.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Johnson & Johnson', 64.72, 0.06, 0.09, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co', 45.73, 0.07, 0.15, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['McDonald\'s Corporation', 36.76, 0.86, 2.40, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Merck & Co., Inc.', 40.96, 0.41, 1.01, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Microsoft Corporation', 25.84, 0.14, 0.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Pfizer Inc', 27.96, 0.4, 1.45, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Coca-Cola Company', 45.07, 0.26, 0.58, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Home Depot, Inc.', 34.64, 0.35, 1.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Procter & Gamble Company', 61.91, 0.01, 0.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['United Technologies Corporation', 63.26, 0.55, 0.88, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Verizon Communications', 35.57, 0.39, 1.11, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.', 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, '9/1 12:00am']
    ];



    function change(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    function pctChange(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }
    // create the data store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        fields: [{
            name: 'company'
        }, {
            name: 'price',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'change',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'pctChange',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'lastChange',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'
        }],
        data: myData
    });
    // create the Grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Company',
            locked: true,
            width: 200,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        }, {
            text: 'Price',
            width: 125,
            sortable: false,
            locked: true,
            renderer: 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price'
        }, {
            text: 'Change',
            width: 125,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: change,
            dataIndex: 'change'
        }, {
            text: '% Change',
            width: 125,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange'
        }, {
            text: 'Last Updated',
            width: 135,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Locking Grid Column',
        renderTo: 'grid-example',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any version either 3 or 4 is ok for me.None of them has such feature.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html

When you lock a column, it moves the column to the far left and stacks it with the other locked columns. If it didn't do that then the whole scrolling interaction wouldn't work from a user experience point of view.

Comment: I ran mentioned example  ,when I tried to lock the second column along with first one ,both of them disappeared.

Comment: any of them.ie and chrome and mozilaa just first two columns disappeared ,after i assigned locked attribute to them.only first column locked worked ok.

Comment: here's a shot of what I'm getting when I lock two columns in Firefox... http://i.imgur.com/7jBsN.png

Comment: http://imgur.com/HkHSQ thas my result ,I ran exactly the same sample, but added locked property to second column.May be I should do something else?

Comment: what version of firefox are you using alekoo?

Comment: its possibly an issue with your version of windows as well, are you running xp?

Comment: currently os is win7,though I beilive that os and browser version as nothing to do with this problem ,can You send me your js code?

Comment: I'm running the exact code from the sencha example, is yours different in anyway? Have you got any extensions on firefox? If so, try running firefox in safe mode

Comment: no extensions,no parameters changes ,just fresh installed FF.It's working until I mark second column as locked. Can You send Your js code ?

Comment: I'm running it on the example that they have, the link I have posted in my answer. Have you tried the link?

Comment: Yes of course,but there they are locking only first column ,that's working identically in my comp,but second column locking creates problems

Comment: That is the only changes to initial code:
{
                text: 'Price',
                width: 125,
                sortable: true,
                locked: true,
                renderer: 'usMoney',
                dataIndex: 'price'
            }

Comment: can you edit the original question and add in all of your code? or post your working example?

Comment: nope, I can't seem to replicate the issue you're having. Can you post a bug report on ExtJS forum?

Comment: can you tell me how you are freezing multiple columns?